# Bad URL NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, url, nsurlconnection

i am stuck with very bad issue as  I am getting

```
   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x1d80fca0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1d8d0100 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}error !
```

I am using following url , and there is not white space in URL , why this error is occuring

```
    http://xxxxxxx.com/api/webservices/webservice.php?method=myProfile&uid=14&sid=23a2q6g70ikliv4jjkjjcl0im6&gid=50317
```

Please help , how to sort out this problem.

Comment: Does the same URL work in your browser? If not then the error message is probably correct and the URL is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure url is valid using this method.

-(BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {

```
NSString *urlRegEx =
@"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|
([-|_])*))+";

NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 

return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
```

}

and check [CFNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html) class ref